# Froala Rails wraps around textarea

Tags: ruby-on-rails, froala

I am trying to implement froala editor in my rails application but the editor wraps around the textarea and even the label is editable

Here is my form

```
<%= simple_form_for([:admin, @article], class: 'form') do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, label: 'Title' %>
<%= f.input :text, id: 'text', as: :textarea %>
<%= f.association :category, label: 'Category' %>
<%= f.association :tags, label: 'Tags' %>
<%= f.input :photo, as: :file %>
<%= f.submit @article.new_record? ? 'Post Article' : 'Update Article', class: 'btn btn-success btn-block btn-medium' %>
```

and this is the result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Change from f.input to f.input_field